Change limits of double integral
Let $0<x<a$ and $0<y<a$ if I want to calculate the area of that square the integral is
$$\int_0^adx \int_0^ady=a^2$$
now if I want to change variables to sum and difference: $$S= x-y$$ $$s=\frac{x+y}{2}$$ than the limits is
$$\int_0^{a/2}ds \int_{-2s}^{2s}dS + \int_{a/2}^ads \int_{-2(a-s)}^{2(a-s)}dS$$
I understand this gives the correct results but how one gets the limits of S?

Would you consider changing one or both of the variable names in your second coordinate system? It's not ideal for them to be the upper & lower case versions of the same letter, especially if it's one for which those versions just differ in size. A common convention is$$u=\frac{x-y}{2},,v=\frac{x+y}{2}$$(I'm not sure why your $S$ has an extra factor of 2). Another uses $\sqrt{2}$ denominators, so the Jacobian determinant becomes $1$.

@J.G.  Same reason.  $$\begin{Vmatrix}\partial_x(x-y) & \partial_y(x-y)\\tfrac 12\partial_x(x+y)&\tfrac 12\partial_y(x+y)\end{Vmatrix}=\begin{Vmatrix}1 & -1\\tfrac 12&\tfrac 12\end{Vmatrix}=1$$

@GrahamKemp Sure, but it's asymmetrical.

I would suggest you just look at the image of the integraion region after the change of variables. To do so, draw the $(u, v)$-plane, defined by the transformation:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
x+y &= 2u \\ 
x-y &= v
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
and depict the integration area. This is most easily done by inspecting where the corners of the square map under such transform and utilising the fact that a linear transform is continuous (a line maps into a line).
Having done that, you obtain a shape that is a rhombus with its leftmost corner at the origin and insides bounded by the lines: $v=\pm2u$, and $v=\pm(2u-2a)$. Now the boundaries are fairly easy to be put, you just travel along the $u$-axis, where $u \in [0; a]$ and $v$ changes according to the bounding lines.
As a matter of fact, the rhombus is symmetric around the point $(\frac{a}{2}; 0)$ both vertically and horizontally, so you can actually use it to simplify the integral to:
$$
\int_0^a du\int_{\phi(u)}^{\psi(u)}dv = 
4\int_0^\frac{a}{2}du\int_{0}^{2u}dv  =
4\int_0^\frac{a}{2}2udu = 4u^2\Bigg|_0^\frac{a}{2} = a^2
$$
